# What is "a defining question"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder if it has any special meaning or its meaning is just a combination of those three words.

"The Bank for International Settlements – known as the central bankers’ bank – highlighted the vulnerability of consumer, business and government finances to interest rate increases in its 174-page quarterly report. Claudio Borio, the head of the monetary and economic department, described this as “**a defining question** for the global economy”."

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/money/2017/sep/17/growing-risk-of-debt-trap-if-interest-rates-remain-low-bank-warns

Comment: It's not a fixed phrase with an idiomatic meaning. You might paraphrase as "a question whose answer defines (or contributes substantially to defining) the state of the global economy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phrase is used to identify the key issue or component needed to understand a larger issue.  It is the question that needs to be answered before any real knowledge, in a specific area, can be achieved.  Though, what is or is not a key issue is often overstated.

In your example, Claudio Borio considers understanding the relationship between the fragility of consumer/business/government finances and interest rate increases to be paramount, in order to understand the global economy.

In other words, according to Claudio, it is impossible to understand the global economy without understanding the previous relationship first.

[Here](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/28/fashion/a-defining-question-in-an-iphone-age-live-for-the-moment-or-record-it.html?mcubz=0) is a good example of the phrase used in a NY Times article.  I think the article, and comments about the article, help define how the phrase is often used.